# how to inspect the element for svg xmlns?

Tags: svg, xpath

I am trying to detect one element which is related to svg.

Here is the link for svg image -

https://secure.stg1.espresso.cruisingpower.com/cruisingpower/content/shared_assets/svg/svg_r_AN_1734/IDP-DECK08.svg

This is the image for the cruise where you can see the lots of rooms with colors. I want to click on any of the room. Lets say Room# - 8320 (At lower bottom of the image)

I have tried various combination of xpath. But couldn't find any luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
//*[text()="8624"]
```

but I do not think it's clickable.

Comment: No, it's not working. i tried with different combination also. Still no luck.